# File upload via 2 stage REST architecture

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I am writing a public facing RESTful service which is mostly just a wrapper around another RESTful service (main-service).

I need to accept file uploads but cannot really store any of the files on my service's server. Would it be possible to stay transient between the main-service and browser so that I simply pass the file data coming from browser as multipart-form POST to the backend (main-service)?

If so, how and any architecture guidelines? If not, what is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But it heavily depends on the technology you (can) use.

Comment: Can you explain how that is possible? I need more of a high level architectural guideline.